# CSS selector needed to select the NEXT row in a table

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have simplified the situation as shown below:

```
 <table>
  ...
  <tr><td>....</td><td><button...>delete</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>somestuff</td><td>some other stuff</td></tr>

 </table>
```

On click of the delete button, I delete the row by using:

```
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

My question is, how do I delete the next row too using some CSS selector for the next row.
I have a work-around by using a running id number for each row, picking the id # of the one deleted, incrementing it and then using it to delete the next row, but I think there must be some CSS selector to select  the next row.

Comment: Do you mean `$(this).closest('tr').next()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to separate finding the rows, and removing them - otherwise you'll get unpredictable results.

```
var rowA = $(this).closest('tr');
var rowB = rowA.next();

rowA.remove();
rowB.remove();
```

Comment: Your answer requires the least amount of understanding of what-if possibilities of what happens once you delete the row. Is a reference to its next still defined? etc... Accepting. Thanks!

Comment: and helps document which rows are deleted by substituting rowA and rowB by more descriptive names.

Answer (score 2):

Removing both at once:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().addBack().remove();
```

[`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) replaces [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) for jQuery 1.8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').remove();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: TahiKheli. Yes. It should work too. Thanks. Upvoting.

Comment: TahiKheli. Yes. It should work too. Thanks. Upvoting. Coming to think of it, yours is the best solution technically. Just that in my situation, the answer accepted would be easier to document because I need to specify which rows I am deleting and the intermediate variable names serve that purpose.  THANKS anyway.

Comment: Primary aim to resolve your issue. Glad it is resolved. Cheers buddy happy coding. :)