# How to select value from the next row via pup?

Tags: html, html-table, css-selectors, pup

Given the following table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Buzz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming I don't know the fixed position of the value, I'd like to select the 2nd row by giving the 1st row column name, for example:

- Foo => 1
- Bar => 2
- Buzz => 3

---

Currently I know how to get the name of the column (1st row):

```
$ pup -f table.html 'td:contains("Foo") text{}'
Foo
```

I know how to return the next column by:

```
$ pup -f table.html 'td:contains("Foo") + td text{}'
Bar
```

I would expect to get the next row by:

```
$ pup -f table.html 'td:contains("Foo") + tr text{}'
```

but it doesn't return anything (I expect to be `1`).

Here is [the solution with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21415950/55075), but I expect the solution to work with `pup` command.

I've checked [Mozilla's CSS selector docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), but I couldn't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 3):

Your selector

```
td:contains("Foo") + tr text{}
```

represents the text of a `tr` that directly follows a `td`, as a sibling. Based on the table structure, `tr`s aren't siblings of `td`s — they are their parents.

pup features its own `:parent-of()` pseudo-class, listed [here](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup#implemented-selectors), but that won't be enough for your needs since there's no way for you to select the next row's `td` in the same column as the one you have. Selectors 4's column combinator `||` does exactly what you want, but it's not implemented anywhere, and certainly not in pup. It won't be trivial to do this with any command-line tool that primarily works with CSS selectors.